# Refactor, maybe using a block? or Proc? How to run majority of method, but change one small part

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, refactoring

What is the best way to refactor this so I don't have as much repeat code? I mainly have a template of  method and only one part is changed for all of the separate methods.  I would think there is a way to refactor.

## Step 1 needs to run

```
def method1 (title,field2)
    t=title.to_s
    field2.each do |f|
        field_name =f.to_s
            sub_method1(t,field_name)
    end
end
```

## Step 2 needs to run next

```
def method2 (title,field2)
    t=title.to_s
    field2.each do |f|
        field_name =f.to_s
            sub_method2(t,field_name)
    end
end
```

## Step 3 runs after

```
def method3 (title,field2)
    t=title.to_s
    field2.each do |f|
        field_name =f.to_s
            sub_method3(t,field_name)
    end
end
```

## Step 4 is last

```
def method4 (title,field2)
    t=title.to_s
    field2.each do |f|
        field_name =f.to_s
            sub_method4(t,field_name)
    end
end
```

## This will not work

```
def method1 (title,field2)
    t=title.to_s
    field2.each do |f|
        field_name =f.to_s
            sub_method1(t,field_name)
            sub_method2(t,field_name)
            sub_method3(t,field_name)
            sub_method4(t,field_name)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what blocks are for.

```
def method(title, field)
  field2.each { |field| yield(title.to_s, field.to_s) }
end
```

You can then call your method like this:

```
method(title, field) { |t, f| submethodX(t, f) }
```

This way you can have one call for each step you need, and inject the changing code via the block on the call site while leaving the shared code in the definition of `method`.